# Statement for specific truth table

Tags: javascript, truthtable

I have three variables, `variation`, `attribute` and `active` for which I need to create an `if` statement for the following truth table:

| variation | attribute | active | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [object Object] | 'color' | true | TRUE |
| undefined | undefined | undefined | TRUE |
| [object Object] | 'color' | false | FALSE |

But I can't think of a smart and compact statement for the case, unless I write all desired `true` scenarios in an `or` separated long statement...

Can someone please help me with this?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/princeofabyss/fxncs0zo/) is a quick fiddle for you.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can negate all the values to booleans and check if they are all equal:

```js
!variation == !attribute && !attribute == !active
```

---

Values in JavaScript can be either **truthy** or **falsy**.

- [object Object], 'color', true => truthy
- undefined, false => falsy

So when you put the logical NOT operator (`!`) before a value, you effectively negate it, meaning all truthy values become the boolean `false` and all falsy values are cast to the boolean `true`.

---

Your truth table seems to return true when all of the variables are truthy or when all of the variables are falsy, and returns false when they are mixed.

So it essentially checks that all the values, when casted to booleans, are equal. So the condition above casts the values to opposite booleans and checks that they are all the same.

Comment: Oh wow! That works like a charm I'd never imagine that without trying it first, but indeed it works! Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: see updated answer